# CNN for a matrix of numbers

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, transformer-model

I've been trying to learn more about how CNNs work as I'm trying to implement one inside of a Transformer, but all the examples I've seen use CNNs for images. Since images are technically numbers, would it be possibly to input a matrix of numbers to a CNN? And are there any examples/links that do this?

The part that's confusing me the most is the filters, as those are supposed to look for certain features in the images, but could those be manipulated to look for patterns in the numbers instead?

Comment: Did the comment belowe addressed your concern?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [link](https://aigents.co/data-science-blog/publication/introduction-to-convolutional-neural-networks-cnns), CNNs actually work on matrices of numbers. The input to a CNN is a matrix of NxM (n width, M height) with C channels (3 in the case of RGB). The so called "images" are represented by these matrices. Thus, the filters actually learn to detect patterns in the  numbers.